# How do I custom style the default "Nav Menu" of Communities Customer Account Theme?

Tags: community, menu, theme-branding

I want to custom restyle the default **NAV MENU** CSS of the Communities Customer Account Portal Theme to match my company branding.

How or whats the best location to over-write default out of box style but still keep the menu?

Has anyone ever successfully Re-styled the default **Nav Menu** with your own branding styles, font sizes and etc inside a Communities Theme?

Please let me know or point me to the correct direction. If there are concerns or if this is a limitation of Sales Force Theme branding, please let me know and advise accordingly. My management wants to re-customize the Default Nav Menu.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the below options for customizing the "Customer Account Portal" template.

You can find more details on customizing templates on the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize.htm).

1. You can customize the text and background color of the navigation menu from "Builder --> Theme --> Colors" and then selecting the Text and Background Color as depicted in the image below.
   [image]
2. You can edit the default template CSS from the same menu as depicted below. For details refer [CSS Overrides Migration for the Navigation Menu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_nav_menu_css.htm) and the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm). **However**, its not recommended to edit the default CSS because of the reason mentioned in the document.
   [image]

   > However, use custom CSS sparingly because future releases of template components might not support your CSS customizations.

---

Anything beyond this would need a custom theme template to be created. More details can be found on the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_theme.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Since Winter '18, it is possible to set the Text and Background color for the Navigation Menu separately in the Branding settings of the template.

The Header Background Color setting mentioned in the accepted answer, now controls the background of the header containing the search bar and the profile link. It does not influence the navigation menu anymore.

[image]

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_brandingprops.htm

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to export this style so that when deploying the community another environment I don't need to set the style again?

Comment: It's better to ask this question separately than posting it as an answer to an existing question, but this is indeed possible, either by using the SiteDotCom or ExperienceBundle metadata types

Comment: It's case by case in my org I didn't get the options. Probably compatibility issue since my community was built a couple of years ago. I might have to rebuild the template from scratch to get this options. So I am not trying to solve this problem for now

Comment: Yea, the available options change almost every release, but only if you update the template.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. How to catch up the release? Just following release note? There is any tool to know what I metadata I need to upgrade etc...

Comment: If you go to the Community Builder, click on the Settings icon and then go the Updates, you can see whether or not you're using the latest version of the template. From there you can also upgrade if applicable.

Comment: It says I am using the latest.

Comment: If you created the community years ago, then it's also likely you are using an old template, such as Napili. I advice you to create a new question if you need help with this.

Comment: I've created new post reg. on this. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311893/navbar-color-option-and-switch-theme-option-not-available-somehow-in-the-communi