# Lightning Community Pre-Built template nav text colors

Tags: lightning, community, css

hoping for some help!

I'm really struggling to change the text color of my navigation items on a pre-built template. It's the Jepson one.

The inspector tool reveals the css classes I need to change, and changing the font size works, but nothing I do seems to change the actual text color. I've included images. Someone please help me modify the CSS to actually make the color change. It's driving me absolutely nuts and I am sure it is a simple solution. Just want to change it to any color except black.

[image: What I want to Change]
[image: Inspector Results]
[image: My CSS]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226955/how-do-i-custom-style-the-default-nav-menu-of-communities-customer-account-the#226964) (and the answer), if that helps? It seems very similar problem that you are into.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using the default template, so those options are not there for the header text color palette option. I'll look around though!

Comment: Then you will need to make the changes in the CSS that your template is using. The one you posted in the question is to override for default templates only.