# Navbar color option and switch theme option not available somehow in the community builder

Tags: community-builder

I am debugging some old community template which has been used by customers for a few years. All the functionalities we implemented are working fine, but some settings are missing. I can't change the theme and don't get navigation text color setting in the builder. If I go to Settings > Theme > Manage it says "upgrade to the latest version of your community template" However if I go to Settings > Updates it says "You're already using the latest version of your template :my template"

Is there any way to manually update the template so I have access to all settings available with the latest version?

Comment: Which community template are you currently using? What does it say on the Updates tab where you have "You're already using the latest version of your template :my template"

Comment: Just the name previous developer specified when she/he made this template. Is there any way to know which salesforce template was used to develop originally? In BrandingSet-meta.xml it says "cpt:branding-cpt"

Comment: If you go to the Administration part of the community, then to Settings, you will see which Template is used and there you can also change it. It sounds like you didn't use an out of the box template but made one yourself, correct?